# How to make an edit Text accept a city name only?

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to make a login page in android studio where the user has to enter their city but I am having trouble making an edit Text which only accepts a city name. Does anyone have any suggestions? A spinner will be even better. For now I have used a very inefficient method of making this list.

```
    {
    "A", "Aachen", "Aalborg", "Aarhus", "Aba", "Abadan", "Abaetetuba", "Abakan", "Abbotabad", "Abbotsford", "Abengourou", "Abeokuta", "Aberdeen", "Abha", "Abidjan", "Abiko", "Abilene", "Abohar", "Abu", "Abu", "Abu", "Abuja", "Açailândia", "Acapulco", "Acarigua", "Accra", "Achalpur", "Acheng", "Achinsk", "Adama", "Adana", "Adapazarı", "Addis", "Adelaide", "Aden", "Adhamiyah", "Adilabad", "Adityapur", "Adıyaman", "Ado-Ekiti", "Adoni", "Afyon", "Agadir", "Agartala", "Ageo", "Agra", "Ağrı", "Águas", "Aguascalientes", "Ahmedabad", "Ahmednagar", "Ahome", "Ahvaz", "Ain", "Aix-en-Provence", "Aizawl", "Aizuwakamatsu", "Ajax", "Ajman", "Ajmer", "Akashi", "Akbarpur", "Akesu", "Akishima", "Akita", "Akola", "Akron", "Aksaray", "Aktau", "Aktobe", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al", "Al-Fashir", "Al-Hasakah", "Al-Mejar", "Al-Qa"im", "Al-Qurnah", "Al-Rifa"i", "Al-Shatrah", "Al-Suwaira", "Al-Thuqbah", "Al-Wahda", "Alagoinhas", "Alajuela", "Alandur", "Alanya", "Alappuzha", "Albacete", "Albuquerque", "Alcalá", "Alchevsk", "Alcobendas", "Alcorcón", "Aleppo", "Alexandra", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", "Algeciras", "Algiers", "Alicante", "Aligarh", "Alkmaar", "Allahabad", "Allappuzha", "Allentown", "Almada", "Almaty", "Almere", "Almería", "Almetyevsk", "Almirante", "Alor", "Alphen", "Altamira", "Altay", "Alvorada", "Alwar", "Amadora", "Amagasaki", "Amarah", "Amaravati", "Amarillo", "Ambala", "Ambala", "Ambarnath", "Ambato", "Ambattur", "Ambikapur", "Ambon", "Ambur", "Americana", "Amersfoort", "Amiens", "Amman", "Amol", "Amravati", "Amreli", "Amritsar", "Amroha", "Amsterdam", "Anaco", "Anaheim", "Anand", "Ananindeua", "Anantapur", "Anantnag", "Anápolis", "Anchorage", "Ancona", "Anda", "Anderlecht", "Andijan", "Andimeshk", "Andong", "Andria", "Angarsk", "Angeles", "Angers", "Angono", "Angra", "Angren", "Anjō", "Anju", "Ankang", "Ankara", "Anlu", "Ann", "Annaba", "Anqing", "Ansan", "Anshan", "Anshun", "Antakya", "Antalya", "Antananarivo", "Antioch", "Antipolo", "Antofagasta", "Antsirabe", "Antwerp", "Anyama", "Anyang,", "Anyang,", "Aomori", "Apalit", "Aparecida", "Apartadó", "Apeldoorn", "Apopa", "Apucarana", "Aqaba", "Ar-Ramtha", "Aracaju", "Araçatuba", "Arad", "Araguaína", "Araguari", "Arak", "Arapiraca", "Arapongas", "Arar", "Araraquara", "Araras", "Araruama", "Araucária", "Araure", "Arayat", "Ardabil", "Arequipa", "Argenteuil", "Arica", "Ariquemes", "Arkhangelsk", "Arlington,", "Arlington,", "Armavir", "Armenia", "Arnhem", "Arrah", "Artyom", "Arusha", "Arvada", "Arzamas", "Asahikawa", "Asaka", "Asansol", "Aşgabat", "Ashaiman", "Ashdod", "Ashikaga", "Ashkelon", "Ashoknagar", "Asmara", "Assis", "Astrakhan", "Asunción", "Aswan", "Asyut", "Athens", "Athens,", "Athi", "Atibaia", "Atlanta", "Atsugi", "Atushi", "Atyrau", "Auckland", "Augsburg", "Augusta,", "Aurangabad,", "Aurangabad,", "Aurora,", "Aurora,", "Austin", "Avadi", "Avellaneda", "Awasa", "Ayacucho", "Aydın", "Azamgarh", "Azua","Babol", "Babruysk", "Bacabal", "Bacău", "Bacolod", "Bacoor", "Badajoz", "Badalona", "Badlapur", "Bafoussam", "Bagaha", "Bagalkot", "Bagé", "Baghdad", "Baghlan", "Bago", "Bago", "Baguio", "Bahadurgarh", "Baharampur", "Bahawalnagar", "Bahawalpur", "Bahía", "Bahir", "Bahraich", "Baia", "Baicheng", "Baidoa", "Baidyabati", "Baise", "Baishan", "Baiyin", "Bajos", "Bakersfield", "Baku", "Balakovo", "Balashikha", "Baleshwar", "Balıkesir", "Balikpapan", "Baliuag", "Ballarat", "Ballia", "Bally,", "Bally,", "Balneário", "Bălți", "Baltimore", "Balurghat", "Bamako", "Bamenda", "Banda", "Banda", "Bandar", "Bandar", "Bandar", "Bandar-e", "Bandar-e", "Bandırma", "Bandung", "Bangalore", "Bangaon", "Bangkok", "Bangui", "Banha", "Bani", "Baní", "Banja", "Banjarmasin", "Banjul", "Bankura", "Bansberia", "Banswara", "Baoding", "Baoji", "Baoshan", "Baotou", "Baqubah", "Barakaldo", "Baraki", "Baran", "Baranagar", "Baranovichi", "Barasat", "Baraut", "Barbacena", "Barcarena", "Barcelona,", "Barcelona", "Bardhaman", "Bareilly", "Bari", "Barika", "Bariloche", "Barinas", "Baripada", "Barisal", "Barka", "Barnala", "Barnaul", "Barquisimeto", "Barra", "Barrackpur", "Barrancabermeja", "Barranquilla", "Barreiras", "Barretos", "Barrie", "Barshi", "Barueri", "Baruta", "Barysaw", "Basel", "Bashiqa", "Basirhat", "Basra", "Basti", "Bat", "Batala", "Batam", "Batangas", "Bataysk", "Bathinda", "Batman", "Batna", "Baton", "Battambang", "Batu", "Batu", "Batumi", "Bauru", "Bawshar", "Bayambang", "Bayamo", "Bayamón", "Bayannur", "Bayawan", "Baybay", "Bazhou", "Beau-Bassin", "Beaumont", "Beawar", "Béchar", "Beed", "Beersheba", "Begusarai", "Behbahan", "Bei"an", "Beihai", "Beijing", "Beipiao", "Beira", "Beirut", "Beit", "Béjaïa", "Bekasi", "Belém", "Belfast", "Belford", "Belgaum", "Belgorod", "Belgrade", "Bellary", "Bellevue", "Bello", "Belo", "Bengbu", "Benghazi", "Bengkulu", "Benguela", "Beni", "Benito", "Benoni", "Bento", "Benxi", "Beppu", "Berbera", "Berdyansk", "Berezniki", "Bergamo", "Bergen", "Bergisch", "Berhampur", "Berkane", "Berkeley", "Berlin", "Bern", "Berrechid", "Besançon", "Betim", "Bettiah", "Betul", "Bhadrak", "Bhadravati", "Bhadreswar", "Bhagalpur", "Bhalswa", "Bhalwal", "Bharatpur,", "Bharatpur,", "Bharuch", "Bhatpara", "Bhavnagar", "Bhilai", "Bhilwara", "Bhimavaram", "Bhimdatta", "Bhind", "Bhiwadi", "Bhiwandi", "Bhiwani", "Bhopal", "Bhubaneswar", "Bhuj", "Bhusawal", "Białystok", "Bidar", "Bidhannagar", "Bielefeld", "Bielsko-Biała", "Bihar", "Bijapur", "Bikaner", "Bila", "Bilaspur", "Bilbao", "Billings", "Biñan", "Binangonan", "Binjai", "Bintulu", "Binzhou", "Biratnagar", "Birgunj", "Birigui", "Birjand", "Birmingham,", "Birmingham", "Bishkek", "Bishoftu", "Biskra", "Bissau", "Bitung", "Biysk", "Bizerte", "Blackburn", "Blackpool", "Blagoveshchensk", "Blantyre", "Blida", "Blitar", "Bloemfontein", "Blumenau", "Bnei", "Bo", "Boa", "Bobo-Dioulasso", "Boca", "Bocaue", "Bochum", "Bogor", "Bogota", "Bogra", "Boise", "Bojnord", "Bokaro", "Boksburg", "Bole", "Bologna", "Bolton", "Bolu", "Bolzano", "Boma", "Bonao", "Bongao", "Bonn", "Borama", "Bordeaux", "Bordj", "Bordj", "Borujerd", "Bosaso", "Boston", "Botad", "Botoșani", "Botou", "Botshabelo", "Bottrop", "Botucatu", "Bou", "Bouaké", "Bouïra", "Boulder", "Boulogne-Billancourt", "Bournemouth", "Bozhou", "Bradford", "Braga", "Bragança", "Bragança", "Brăila", "Brampton", "Brasília", "Brașov", "Bratislava", "Bratsk", "Braunschweig", "Brazzaville", "Breda", "Bremen", "Bremerhaven", "Brescia", "Brest,", "Brest,", "Bridgeport", "Brighton", "Brisbane", "Bristol", "Brno", "Brownsville", "Bruges", "Brusque", "Brussels", "Bryansk", "Bucaramanga", "Bucharest", "Bucheon", "Budapest", "Budaun", "Buenaventura", "Buenos", "Buffalo", "Bujumbura", "Bukan", "Bukavu", "Bukhara", "Bulan", "Bulandshahr", "Bulawayo", "Bundi", "Buôn", "Buraidah", "Burao", "Burari", "Burbank", "Burewala", "Burgas", "Burgos", "Burhanpur", "Burlington,", "Burnaby", "Bursa", "Busan", "Bushehr", "Butuan", "Butwal", "Buxar", "Buzău", "Bydgoszcz", "Bytom","Cabanatuan", "Cabimas", "Cabo", "Cabo", "Cabuyao", "Cachoeirinha", "Cachoeiro", "Cadiz", "Cádiz", "Caen", "Cagayan", "Cagliari", "Cagua", "Caguas", "Cainta", "Cairns", "Cairo", "Cajamarca", "Calabar", "Calama", "Calamba", "Calapan", "Calbayog", "Calgary", "Cali", "Caloocan", "Calumpit", "Cẩm", "Camaçari", "Camagüey", "Camaragibe", "Cambridge,", "Cambridge,", "Cambridge", "Cametá", "Campeche", "Campina", "Campinas", "Campo", "Campo", "Campos", "Cần", "Çanakkale", "Canberra", "Cancún", "Candaba", "Candelaria", "Cangzhou", "Canoas", "Capas", "Cape", "Cape", "Cap-Haïtien", "Capiatá", "Caracas", "Caraguatatuba", "Carapicuíba", "Carcar", "Cardiff", "Cariacica", "Carlsbad", "Carolina", "Carora", "Carrefour", "Carrollton", "Cartagena", "Cartagena", "Cartagena", "Cartago", "Cartago", "Caruaru", "Carúpano", "Cary", "Casablanca", "Cascavel", "Castanhal", "Castellón", "Catacamas", "Catanduva", "Catania", "Catbalogan", "Cauayan,", "Cauayan,", "Caucaia", "Cavite", "Caxias", "Caxias", "Cebu", "Cedar", "Celaya", "Centennial,", "Central", "Champdani", "Chandannagar", "Chandausi", "Chandigarh", "Chandler", "Chandrapur", "Changchun", "Changde", "Changji", "Changsha", "Changshu", "Changwon", "Changzhi", "Changzhou", "Chaohu", "Chaoyang", "Chaozhou", "Chapecó", "Charleroi", "Charleston", "Charlotte", "Chas", "Chatham-Kent", "Chattanooga", "Cheboksary", "Chelyabinsk", "Chemnitz", "Chengde", "Chengdu", "Chennai", "Chenzhou", "Cheonan", "Cheongju", "Cherepovets", "Cherkasy", "Cherkessk", "Chernihiv", "Chernivtsi", "Chesapeake", "Chester", "Chetumal", "Chhapra", "Chhatarpur", "Chhindwara", "Chía", "Chiang", "Chiayi", "Chiba", "Chibi", "Chicago", "Chiclayo", "Chifeng", "Chigasaki", "Chihuahua", "Chikmagalur", "Chikusei", "Chikushino", "Chilakaluripet", "Chillán", "Chilpancingo", "Chimalhuacán", "Chimbote", "Chimoio", "Chinandega", "Chincha", "Chingola", "Chiniot", "Chipata", "Chirchiq", "Chishtian", "Chişinău", "Chita", "Chitradurga", "Chittagong", "Chittoor", "Chittorgarh", "Chitungwiza", "Chizhou", "Chlef", "Chōfu", "Choloma", "Choluteca", "Chonburi", "Chongjin", "Chongqing", "Chorzów", "Christchurch", "Chula", "Chuncheon", "Chungju", "Churu", "Chuxiong", "Chuzhou", "Ciego", "Ciénaga", "Cienfuegos", "Cincinnati", "Cirebon", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Ciudad", "Cixi", "Cizre", "Clarksville", "Clearwater", "Clermont-Ferrand", "Cleveland", "Cluj-Napoca", "Coacalco", "Coatzacoalcos", "Cochabamba", "Codó", "Coimbatore", "Coimbra", "Colatina", "Colchester", "Colima", "Cologne", "Colombo", "Colombo", "Colón", "Colorado", "Columbia,", "Columbia,", "Columbus,", "Columbus,", "Comayagua", "Comilla", "Comitán", "Comodoro", "Conakry", "Concepción", "Concepcion", "Concord", "Concordia", "Conselheiro", "Consolacion", "Constanţa", "Constantine", "Contagem", "Copenhagen", "Copiapó", "Coquimbo", "Coquitlam", "Coral", "Córdoba", "Córdoba,", "Córdoba,", "Cork", "Çorlu", "Corona", "Coronel", "Coronel", "Corpus", "Corrientes", "Çorum", "Corumbá", "Costa", "Cotabato", "Cotia", "Cotonou", "Cottbus", "Coventry", "Craiova", "Crato", "Crawley", "Criciúma", "Cúa", "Cuauhtémoc", "Cuautitlán", "Cuautla", "Cubatão", "Cúcuta", "Cuddalore", "Cuenca", "Cuernavaca", "Cuiabá", "Culiacán", "Cumaná", "Curicó", "Curitiba", "Cusco", "Cuttack", "Częstochowa","Da Lat", "Da Nang", "Dabgram", "Dąbrowa", "Dadu", "Daegu", "Daejeon", "Daet", "Dagupan", "Dahod", "Daitō", "Dakar", "Dali", "Dalian", "Dallas", "Dallupura", "Daloa", "Daly", "Damanhur", "Damascus", "Damietta", "Dammam", "Damoh", "Danao", "Danapur", "Dandong", "Dangyang", "Danjiangkou", "Danlí", "Danyang", "Daqing", "Dar", "Daraga", "Darbhanga", "Darjeeling", "Darmstadt", "Darwin", "Daska", "Dasmariñas", "Daşoguz", "Datia", "Datong", "Davangere", "Davao", "Dawei", "Dayton", "Dazhou", "Debrecen", "Deesa", "Dehiwala-Mount", "Dehradun", "Dehri", "Deir", "Delft", "Delhi", "Delhi", "Delicias", "Delmas", "Dengzhou", "Denizli", "Denpasar", "Denton", "Denver", "Deoghar", "Deoli", "Deoria", "Depok", "Dera", "Derbent", "Derby", "Derince", "Derry", "Des", "Dessie", "Detroit", "Dewas", "Deyang", "Dezful", "Dezhou", "Dhahran", "Dhaka", "Dhamtari", "Dhanbad", "Dhangadhi", "Dharan", "Dharmavaram", "Dholpur", "Dhule", "Diadema", "Diaobingshan", "Dibrugarh", "Digos", "Dijon", "Dili", "Dimapur", "Dimitrovgrad", "Dinajpur", "Dinalupihan", "Dindigul", "Dingzhou", "Diourbel", "Dipolog", "Dire", "Divinópolis", "Divo", "Diwaniyah", "Diyarbakır", "Djelfa", "Djibouti", "Dnipro", "Dodoma", "Doha", "Dohuk", "Dombivli", "Donetsk", "Dongchuan", "Dongguan", "Dongtai", "Dongyang", "Dongying", "Dordrecht", "Dortmund", "Dos", "Dos", "Douala", "Dourados", "Downey", "Dresden", "Dubai", "Dublin", "Dudley", "Duisburg", "Duitama", "Dujail", "Dujiangyan", "Dum", "Dumaguete", "Dundee", "Dunedin", "Dunhua", "Dunhuang", "Duque", "Durán", "Durango", "Durban", "Durg", "Durgapur", "Durham", "Durrës", "Dushanbe", "Düsseldorf","Duyun","Düzce","Dzerzhinsk","Eastbourne", "Ebetsu", "Ebina", "Ecatepec", "Ede,", "Ede,", "Edinburgh", "Edirne", "Edmonton", "Eindhoven", "Ekibastuz", "El", "El", "El", "El", "El", "El", "El-Obeid", "El", "El", "El", "El", "Elazığ", "Elbasan", "Elbląg", "Elche", "Eldoret", "Elektrostal", "Elgin", "Elista", "Elizabeth", "Elk", "El-Mahalla", "Eluru", "Embu", "Emmen", "Engels", "English", "Enschede", "Ensenada", "Enshi", "Enugu", "Envigado", "Erbil", "Erfurt", "Erie", "Erlangen", "Erode", "Erzurum", "Escondido", "Escuintla", "Esenler", "Esfahan", "Eskişehir", "Esmeraldas", "Espoo", "Essen", "Etah", "Etawah", "Eugene", "Eujeongbu", "Evansville", "Everett", "Exeter", "Ezhou","Facatativá", "Fairfield", "Faisalabad", "Faizabad", "Fallujah", "Fargo", "Faridabad", "Farrukhabad", "Fasa", "Fatehgarh", "Fatehpur", "Fayetteville", "Fayyum", "Feira", "Fengcheng", "Fenghua", "Fergana", "Fernando", "Ferrara", "Ferraz", "Fes", "Fianarantsoa", "Firozabad", "Firozpur", "Flint", "Florence", "Florencia", "Florianópolis", "Floridablanca", "Floridablanca", "Foggia", "Fontana", "Forlì", "Formosa", "Formosa", "Fort", "Fort", "Fort", "Fort", "Fortaleza", "Foshan", "Foz", "Fquih", "Franca", "Franceville", "Francisco", "Francistown", "Franco", "Frankfurt", "Frederiksberg", "Freetown", "Freiburg", "Fremont", "Fresnillo", "Fresno", "Frisco", "Fu"an", "Fuchu", "Fuenlabrada", "Fuji", "Fujieda", "Fujimi", "Fujimino", "Fujin", "Fujinomiya", "Fujisawa", "Fukaya", "Fukui", "Fukuoka", "Fukushima", "Fukuyama", "Fuling", "Fullerton", "Funabashi", "Funchal", "Fürth", "Fusagasugá", "Fushun", "Fuxin", "Fuyang", "Fuzhou", "Fuzhou","Gabès", "Gaborone", "Gadag-Betgeri", "Gagnoa", "Gainesville", "Galați", "Gandhidham", "Gandhinagar", "Ganganagar", "Gangapur", "Gangavati", "Gangneung", "Gangtok", "Ganzhou", "Gaocheng", "Gapan", "Garanhuns", "Garden", "Garissa", "Garland", "Garoua", "Gatineau", "Gaya", "Gaza", "Gaziantep", "Gdańsk", "Gdynia", "Gebze", "Geelong", "Gejiu", "Geleen-Sittard", "Gelsenkirchen", "Gəncə", "General", "General", "General", "Geneva", "Genoa", "George", "Georgetown", "Germiston", "Getafe", "Ghardaïa", "Gharraf", "Ghaziabad", "Ghazipur", "Ghazni", "Ghent", "Gifu", "Gijón", "Gilbert", "Gingoog", "Girardot", "Giresun", "Giridih", "Giugliano", "Giza", "Glan", "Glasgow", "Glendale,", "Glendale,", "Gliwice", "Gloucester", "Godhra", "Godoy", "Goiânia", "Goicoechea", "Gojra", "Gojra", "Gokal", "Gold", "Golestan", "Goma", "Gómez", "Gonbad-e", "Gonda", "Gondal", "Gondar", "Gondiya", "Gongzhuling", "Gorakhpur", "Gorgan", "Gorom-Gorom", "Gorontalo", "Gorzów", "Gothenburg", "Göttingen", "Governador", "Granada,", "Granada,", "Grand", "Grand", "Gravataí", "Graz", "Greater", "Greater", "Green", "Greensboro", "Grenoble", "Gresham", "Groningen", "Grozny", "Guacara", "Guadalajara", "Guadalupe", "Guagua", "Guanajuato", "Guanare", "Guanghan", "Guangshui", "Guangyuan", "Guangzhou", "Guantánamo", "Guarapari", "Guarapuava", "Guaratinguetá", "Guarenas", "Guarujá", "Guarulhos", "Guatemala", "Guatire", "Guayaquil", "Guaymas", "Gudivada", "Guédiawaye", "Guelma", "Guelmim", "Guelph", "Guigang", "Guilin", "Guimarães", "Guimba", "Guiyang", "Gujiao", "Gujranwala", "Gujrat", "Gujrat", "Gulbarga", "Gulu", "Gumi", "Guna", "Gunsan", "Guntakul", "Guntur", "Gurgaon", "Guri", "Gütersloh", "Guwahati", "Gwalior", "Gwangju", "Gweru", "Gyeongju", "Győr", "Gyumri","Ha", "Haarlem", "Haarlemmermeer", "Habikino", "Habra", "Hachinohe", "Hachiōji", "Hadano", "Haeju", "Hafar", "Hafizabad", "Hagen", "Hagonoy", "The", "Haicheng", "Haifa", "Haikou", "Ha"il", "Hailun", "Haining", "Haiphong", "Hajipur", "Hakodate", "Hakusan", "Haldia", "Haldwani-cum-Kathgodam", "Halifax", "Halisahar", "Halle", "Hama", "Hamadan", "Hamamatsu", "Hamburg", "Hamhung", "Hami", "Hamilton", "Hamilton", "Hamm", "Hampton", "Hamza", "Hanam", "Hancheng", "Handa", "Handan", "Hangzhou", "Hanoi", "Hanover", "Hanumangarh", "Hanzhong", "Haora", "Hapur", "Harar", "Harare", "Harbin", "Hardoi", "Hargeisa", "Haridwar", "Hartford", "Hassan", "Hastsal", "Hat", "Hathras", "Hatsukaichi", "Havana", "Hawally", "Hawija", "Hayward", "Hazaribagh", "Hebi", "Hebron", "Hechi", "Heerlen-Kerkrade", "Hefei", "Hegang", "Heidelberg", "Heihe", "Heilbronn", "Helsingborg", "Helsinki", "Helwan", "Henderson", "Hengshui", "Hengyang", "Heraklion", "Herat", "Heredia", "Hermosillo", "Herne", "Heshan", "Hetian", "Heyuan", "Heze", "Hialeah", "Higashihiroshima", "Higashikurume", "Higashimurayama", "Higashiōmi", "Higashiōsaka", "High", "Higüey", "Hikone", "Hildesheim", "Hilla", "Himamaylan", "Himeji", "Hindaun", "Hindupur", "Hinganghat", "Hino", "Hirakata", "Hiratsuka", "Hirosaki", "Hiroshima", "Hisar", "Hitachi", "Hitachinaka", "Ho", "Hobart", "Hofu", "Hofuf", "Hoima", "Holguín", "Hollywood,", "Holon", "Homs", "Homyel", "Hong", "Honghu", "Honolulu", "Horlivka", "Hortolândia", "Hoshangabad", "Hoshiarpur", "Hospet", "Hospitalet", "Hosur", "Houghly-Chinsura", "Houma", "Houston", "Hoya", "Hpa-An", "Hrodna", "Hsinchu", "Huadian", "Huaian", "Huaibei", "Huaihua", "Huainan", "Huaiyin", "Huambo", "Huancayo", "Huanghua", "Huangshan", "Huangshi", "Huangyan", "Huánuco", "Huaraz", "Huaying", "Hubli–Dharwad", "Hudaida", "Huddersfield", "Huế", "Huelva", "Huhehaote", "Huichon", "Huixian", "Huizhou", "Huludao", "Hulunbuir", "Hunchun", "Huntington", "Huntsville", "Huozhou", "Hurghada", "Huzhou", zane", "Remscheid", "Rennes", "Reno", "Renqiu", "Resende", "Resistencia", "Reus", "Reutlingen", "Rewa", "Rewari", "Reykjavík", "Reynosa", "Ribeirão", "Ribetherham", "Rotterdam", "Rouen", "Round", "Rourkela", "Roxas", "Rubtsovsk", "Ruda", "Rudny", "Rudrapur", "Rufisque", "Rui"an", "Ruichang", "Ruiru", "Ruse", "Russeifa", "Rustaq", "Rustavi", "Ruzhou", "Ryazan", "Rybinsk", "Rybnik", "Rzeszów","S.A.S. Nagar", "Saanich", "Saarbrücken", "Sabadell", "Sabára", "Sabzewar", "Sacaba", "Sacramento,", "Sadiqabad", "Sadr", "Safi", "Saga", "Sagamihara", "Sagar", "Sagay", "Saguenay", "Saham", "Saharanpur", "Saharsa", "Sahiwal", "Saida", "Saidpur", "Saijō", "Saint", "Saint-Denis", "Saint-Denis", "Saint-Étienne", "Saint-Louis", "Saint-Paul", "Saitama", "Sakado", "Sakai,", "Sakakah", "Sakata", "Sakura,", "Salalah", "Salamanca", "Salamanca", "Salatiga", "Salavat", "Salé", "Salem,", "Salem", "Salerno", "Salihorsk", "Salinas,", "Salmiya", "Salt", "Salta", "Saltillo", "Salto", "Salvador", "Salzburg", "Salzgitter", "Samal", "Samara", "Samarinda", "Samarkand", "Samarra", "Samawah", "Sambalpur", "Sambhal", "Samsun", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "San", "Sana"a", "Sanandaj", "Sancti", "Sanda", "Sandakan", "Sangli", "Şanlıurfa", "Sanmenxia", "Sanming", "Sano", "San-Pédro", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santa", "Santana", "Santana", "Santander", "Santarém,", "Santiago", "Santiago", "Santiago", "Santiago", "Santiago", "Santipur", "Santo", "Santo", "Santo", "Santo", "Santo", "Santo", "Santo", "Santo", "Santo", "Santos", "Sanya", "São", "São", "São", "São", "São", "São", "São", "São", "São", "São", "São", "São", "São", "São", "São", "São", "Sapporo", "Sapucaia", "Saqez", "Sarajevo", "Saransk", "Sarapul", "Saratov", "Sargodha", "Sari", "Sariaya", "Sariwon", "Sasaram", "Sasebo", "Saskatoon", "Sassari", "Satara", "Satna", "Satu", "Savannah,", "Saveh", "Sawai", "Sayama", "Schaerbeek", "Scottsdale,", "Seam", "Seattle", "Secunderabad", "Seeb", "Ségou", "Sehore", "Sejong", "Sekondi-Takoradi", "Seleyang", "Semarang", "Semey", "Semnan", "Sendai", "Seongnam", "Seoni", "Seoul", "Serampore", "Seremban", "Sergiyev", "Serpukhov", "Serra", "Sertaozinho", "Sete", "Setif", "Seto", "Settat", "Sevastopol", "Severodvinsk", "Seversk", "Seville", "Sfax", "Shah", "Shahe", "Shahin", "Shahjahanpur", "Shahrekord", "Shahreza", "Shahriar", "Shahrisabz", "Shahrud", "Shakhty", "Shamli", "Shanghai", "Shangluo", "Shangqiu", "Shangrao", "Shangzhi", "Shantou", "Shanwei", "Shaoguan", "Shaowu", "Shaoxing", "Shaoyang", "Sharjah", "Shchyolkovo", "Sheberghan", "Sheffield", "Sheikhu", "Shenyang", "Shenzhen", "Sheopur", "Sherbrooke", ""s-Hertogenbosch", "Shibin", "Shihezi", "Shihung", "Shijiazhuang", "Shikarpur", "Shikohabad", "Shillong", "Shimizu", "Shimla", "Shimoga", "Shimonoseki", "Shinyanga", "Shiraz", "Shishi", "Shishou", "Shivpuri", "Shiyan", "Shizuishan", "Shizuoka", "Shkodër", "Shreveport,", "Shuangcheng", "Shuangyashan", "Shubra", "Shūnan", "Shuozhou", "Shymkent", "Sialkote", "Šiauliai", "Sibiu", "Sibu", "Sidi-bel-Abbès", "Siegen", "Sieverodonetsk", "Siirt", "Sikar", "Sikasso", "Silang", "Silay", "Silchar", "Siliguri", "Simferopol", "Simi", "Simões", "Sincelejo", "Singapore", "Singkawang", "Singrauli", "Sinop", "Sinpo", "Sinuiji", "Sioux", "Siping", "Sirjan", "Sirsa", "Sitapur", "Sittwe", "Sivas", "Siverek", "Siwan", "Sixth", "Skikda", "Skopje", "Slough", "Sloviansk", "Słupsk", "Smederevo", "Smolensk", "Soacha", "Sobral", "Sochi", "Sofia", "Sogamoso", "Sohag", "Sohar", "Soka", "Sokodé", "Solapur", "Soledad", "Solihull", "Solingen", "Songyuan", "Sonipat", "Sorocaba", "Sorsogon", "Sosnowiec", "Soubré", "Souk", "South", "South", "South", "Southampton", "Southend", "Soweto", "Soyapango", "Spanish", "Split", "Spokane,", "Springfield,", "Springfield,", "Springfield,", "Springs", "Sri", "Sri", "Srikakulam", "Srinagar", "Ssabagabo", "St.", "St.", "St.", "St.", "St.", "St.", "Stakhanov", "Stamford,", "Stara", "Stary", "Stavanger", "Stavropol", "Sterling", "Sterlitamak", "Stockholm", "Stockport", "Stockton,", "Stoke-on-Trent", "Strasbourg", "Stuttgart", "Subang", "Subic", "Subotica", "Suceava", "Sucre", "Suez", "Suhaj", "Suihua", "Suining", "Suita", "Suizhou", "Sujangarh", "Sukabumi", "Sukkur", "Sulamaniya", "Sullana", "Sultan", "Sultanbeyli", "Sultanpur", "Sumaré", "Sumgait", "Sumy", "Suncheon", "Sunchon", "Sunderland", "Sungai", "Sunnyvale,", "Sunshine", "Sunyani", "Suqian", "Sur", "Surabaya", "Surakarta", "Surat", "Surat", "Surendranagar", "Surgut", "Surigao", "Surprise", "Surrey", "Suryapet", "Suwayq", "Suwon", "Suzano", "Suzhou,", "Suzhou,", "Suzuka", "Swansea", "Swindon", "Sydney", "Syktyvkar", "Syracuse", "Syracuse,", "Syzran", "Szczecin", "Szeged","Ta’if", "Tabaco", "Taboão", "Tabriz", "Tabuk", "Tabuk", "Tacheng", "Tachikawa", "Tacloban", "Tacna", "Tacoma,", "Tadepalligudem", "Tadipatri", "Taganrog", "Tagbilaran", "Taguig", "Tagum", "Tahoua", "Taian", "Taichung", "Tainan", "Taipei", "Taiping", "Taiyuan", "Taiz", "Taizhou,", "Taizhou,", "Taji", "Tajimi", "Takamatsu", "Takaoka", "Takarazuka", "Takasaki", "Takatsuki", "Tal", "Talavera", "Talca", "Talcahuano", "Taldıqorğan", "Talisay,", "Talisay,", "Tallahassee,", "Tallinn", "Taloqan", "Tama", "Tamale", "Tambaram", "Tambov", "Tampa,", "Tampere", "Tampico", "Tanauan", "Tanay", "Tanchon", "Tandil", "Tandoadam", "Tanga", "Tangail", "Tangerang", "Tangier", "Tangshan", "Tanjung", "Tanjungbalai", "Tanta", "Tanza", "Taonan", "Taourirt", "Tapachula", "Taranto", "Tarapoto", "Taraz", "Târgu-Mureş", "Táriba", "Tarija", "Tarlac", "Tarnów", "Tarragona", "Tarsus", "Tartus", "Tashkent", "Tatuí", "Taubaté", "Taunggyi", "Tauranga", "Tawau", "Taytay", "Taza", "Tbilisi", "Tebessa", "Tebing", "Tecomán", "Tegal", "Tegucigalpa", "Tehran", "Tehuacán", "Teixeira", "Tekirdağ", "Tel", "Telde", "Telford", "Tema", "Temara", "Tembisa", "Temecula,", "Temirtau", "Tempe,", "Temuco", "Tenali", "Tengzhou", "Teófilo", "Tepatitlán", "Tepic", "Teresina", "Teresópolis", "Termez", "Terni", "Ternopil", "Terrassa", "Tete", "Tétouan", "Thai", "Thane", "Thanesar", "Thanjavur", "Thessaloniki", "Thiès", "Thika", "Thimphu", "Thiruvananthapuram", "Thoothukudi", "Thornton", "Thousand", "Thrissur", "Thunder", "Tianjin", "Tianmen", "Tianshui", "Tiaret", "Tieli", "Tieling", "Tijuana", "Tikrit", "Tilburg", "Timișoara", "Timon", "Tipitapa", "Tirana", "Tiruchchirappalli", "Tiruchirappalli", "Tirunelveli", "Tirupati", "Tiruppur", "Tiruvannamalai", "Tiruvottiyur", "Titagarh", "Tizi", "Tlalnepantla", "Tlalpan", "Tlaquepaque", "Tlaxcala", "Tlemoen", "Toamasina", "Tochigi", "Tocuyito", "Toda", "Tōkai", "Tokat", "Tokchon", "Tokorozawa", "Tokushima", "Tokuyama", "Tokyo", "Toledo,", "Toledo", "Toledo,", "Toliara", "Toluca", "Tolyatti", "Tomakomai", "Tomsk", "Tondabayashi", "Tongchuan", "Tonghua", "Tongi", "Tongjiang", "Tongliao", "Tongling", "Tongren", "Tonk", "Toowoomba", "Topeka,", "Torbat-e", "Toride", "Toronto", "Torrance,", "Torrejón", "Torreón", "Toruń", "Tottori", "Touggourt", "Toulon", "Toulouse", "Tours", "Townsville", "Toyama", "Toyohashi", "Toyokawa", "Toyonaka", "Toyota", "Trabzon", "Trece", "Trento", "Três", "Trier", "Trieste", "Trindade", "Tripoli", "Tripoli", "Trois-Rivières", "Trondheim", "Trujillo", "Tsu", "Tsuchiura", "Tsukuba", "Tsuruoka", "Tsuyama", "Tubarão", "Tucson,", "Tucuruí", "Tuguegarao", "Tula", "Tula", "Tulancingo", "Tulsa,", "Tulua", "Tulufan", "Tumaco", "Tumbes", "Tumbes", "Tumen", "Tumkur", "Tunis", "Tunja", "Turbo", "Turgutlu", "Turhal", "Turin", "Turkistan", "Turkmenabat", "Turku", "Tuticorin", "Tuxpan", "Tuxtla", "Tuz", "Tuzla", "Tver", "Tychy", "Tyumen","Ubá", "Ube", "Uberaba", "Uberlândia", "Ubon", "Udaipur", "Udgir", "Udine", "Udon", "Udupi", "Ueda", "Ufa", "Uji", "Ujjain", "Ulaanbaatar", "Ulan", "Ulanqab", "Ulan-Ude", "Ulhasnagar", "Ulm", "Ulsan", "Uluberia", "Ulyanovsk", "Umlazi", "Umuarama", "Unaizah", "Unnao", "Uppsala", "Urasoe", "Urawa", "Urayasu", "Urdaneta", "Urgench", "Uribia", "Urmia", "Uruapan", "Uruguaiana", "Uruma", "Ürümqi", "Uşak", "Ussuriysk", "Utrecht", "Utsunomiya", "Uttarpara", "Uzhhorod","Vacoas-Phoenix", "Vadodara", "Valdivia", "Valencia", "Valencia", "Valencia", "Valenzuela", "Valera", "Valinhos", "Valladolid", "Valle", "Valledupar", "Vallejo", "Valparaíso", "Valparaíso", "Valsad", "Van", "Vancouver,", "Vancouver,", "Vantaa", "Vapi", "Varamin", "Varanasi", "Varginha", "Varna", "Várzea", "Várzea", "Vasai-Virar", "Västerås", "Vaughan", "Veliky", "Vellore", "Venice", "Venlo", "Veracruz", "Veraval", "Verona", "Vespasiano", "Viamão", "Vicente", "Vicenza", "Victoria", "Victorville,", "Vidisha", "Vienna", "Vientiane", "Vigo", "Vihiga", "Vijayawada", "Vila", "Vila", "Villa", "Villa", "Villahermosa", "Villanueva", "Villavicencio", "Villeurbanne", "Vilnius", "Viña", "Vinh", "Vinnytsia", "Viranşehir", "Virginia", "Visakhapatnam", "Visalia", "Vitebsk", "Vitória", "Vitória", "Vitória", "Vitoria-Gasteiz", "Vizianagaram", "Vladikavkaz", "Vladimir", "Vladivostok", "Vlorë", "Volgodonsk", "Volgograd", "Vologda", "Volos", "Volta", "Volzhsky", "Voronezh", "Vosloorus", "Votorantim", "Vũng","Waco", "Wad", "Wafangdian", "Wah", "Wakayama", "Wałbrzych", "Wanica", "Wanzhou", "Warangal", "Wardha", "Warren", "Warrington", "Warsaw", "Washington,", "Waterbury", "Waterloo", "Wau", "Weifang", "Weihai", "Weihui", "Weinan", "Wellington", "Wendeng", "Wenzhou", "West", "West", "West", "West", "Westland", "Westminster", "Whitby", "Wichita", "Wichita", "Wiesbaden", "Willemstad", "Wilmington", "Windhoek", "Windsor", "Winnipeg", "Winston-Salem", "Winterthur", "Włocławek", "Wolfsburg", "Wollongong", "Wolverhampton", "Wonju", "Wonsan", "Worcester", "Wrocław", "Wu"an", "Wuhai", "Wuhan", "Wuhu", "Wuppertal", "Würzburg", "Wuwei", "Wuxi", "Wuxue", "Wuyishan", "Wuzhong", "Wuzhou","Xai-Xai", "Xalapa", "Xiamen", "Xi"an", "Xiangtan", "Xiangyang", "Xianning", "Xiantao", "Xianyang", "Xiaogan", "Xiaoshan", "Xichang", "Xilinhot", "Xingcheng", "Xinghua", "Xingtai", "Xingyi", "Xining", "Xinji", "Xintai", "Xinxiang", "Xinyang", "Xinyi", "Xinyu", "Xinzhou", "Xo‘jayli", "Xochimilco", "Xuancheng", "Xuchang", "Yachiyo", "Yaizu", "Yakeshi", "Yakutsk", "Yalova", "Yamagata", "Yamaguchi", "Yamato,", "Yamoussoukro", "Yamuna", "Yan"an", "Yanbu", "Yancheng", "Yangjiang", "Yangon", "Yangquan", "Yangzhou", "Yanji", "Yantai", "Yao", "Yaoundé", "Yaroslavl", "Yasuj", "Yatsushiro", "Yavatmal", "Yazd", "Yekaterinburg", "Yelets", "Yenakiieve", "Yeosu", "Yerevan", "Yessentuki", "Yevpatoria", "Yibin", "Yichang", "Yichun,", "Yichun,", "Yidu", "Yima", "Yinchuan", "Yingcheng", "Yingkou", "Yingtan", "Yining", "Yiwu", "Yixing", "Yiyang", "Yizheng", "Yogyakarta", "Yokkaichi", "Yokohama", "Yokosuka", "Yonago", "Yong"an", "Yongzhou", "Yonkers", "Yopal", "York", "Yoshkar-Ola", "Yuanjiang", "Yueyang", "Yulin,", "Yulin,", "Yumen", "Yuncheng", "Yusufiyah", "Yuxi", "Yuyao", "Yuzhno-Sakhalinsk", "Yuzhou","Zaanstad", "Zabol", "Zabrze", "Zacatecas", "Zagazig", "Zagreb", "Zahedan", "Zama", "Zamboanga", "Zamora", "Zanjan", "Zanzibar", "Zaoyang", "Zaozhuang", "Zapopan", "Zaporizhia", "Zaragoza", "Zaria", "Zarqa", "Zelenograd", "Zenica", "Zhalantun", "Zhangjiagang", "Zhangjiajie", "Zhangjiakou", "Zhangshu", "Zhangye", "Zhangzhou", "Zhanjiang", "Zhaodong", "Zhaoqing", "Zhaotong", "Zheleznodorozhny", "Zhengzhou", "Zhenjiang", "Zhongshan", "Zhoukou", "Zhoushan", "Zhucheng", "Zhuhai", "Zhuji", "Zhukovsky", "Zhumadian", "Zhuozhou", "Zhuzhou", "Zhytomyr", "Zibo", "Zielona", "Zigong", "Ziguinchor", "Zihuatanejo", "Zinder", "Zipaquirá", "Zixing", "Zlatoust", "Zoetermeer", "Zonguldak", "Zrenjanin", "Zunyi", "Zürich", "Zuwarah", "Zwolle"}
```

Comment: You can try [SearchableSpinner](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner), using this you have to hardcode all the states. You can also use [All states array list](http://code-cocktail.in/indian-states-list-in-php-array-format/)

Comment: I need for all cities and I am working on creating a list with all cities.

Comment: here are [top cities](https://github.com/vinaygaba/Ultimate-String-Array-List/blob/master/Country%20Lists/India/India%20Top%20Cities.xml) of india, you can find list like these on internet easily

Comment: I am trying to get for the whole world. As many as I can

Comment: try to find list for top cities of world

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is to search the city that the user wants from an API (for example: World Cities, GeoDB, etc). In this way you don't have to make a huge list with all the cities of the world.